# Contact Form 7 with Google Analytics - gtag event tracking (Goals)

Tags: google-analytics, contact-form-7, gtag.js

I am trying to set up event tracking with Contact Form 7 in Google Analytics. Google Tag Assistant seems to see the event but it does bot seem to be tracking in Google Analytics. Please see below:

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    gtag('config', 'UA-********-*', {
        'send_page_view': false
    });
    // https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api#event
    gtag('event', 'form_submitted', {
        'event_category': 'lead',
        'event_action': 'Submit',
        'event_action': 'Form',
        'event_value': 1,
    });
    console.log('Form Submitted');
}, false);
```

**Goal Set Up**

[image]

**Google Tag Assist**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your event code (for example you have written the action twice) however the construct is wrong since the syntax for send an event in `gtag` is the following:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

So you have to change you code like this:

```
gtag('event', 'Submit', {
    'event_category': 'form_submitted',
    'event_label': 'Form',
    'value': 1
});
```